# Unexpected behaviour of cached messages of Paho MQTT client on Mosquitto server

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I do use the PAHO C client library in my application. I do subscribe topics with MQTTAsync_subscribe() and QoS set to 1. From what I understand is that 1 means, that a message is send to the client at least one time.

I disconnect the client that subscribed the topic and the client that published the topic is still sending messages to the Mosquitto broker. If I start the subscriber lets say hours later, I get all the buffered messages beginning from the last one when the subscriber was shut down. So far so good! But the problem is, that the messages arrive in the same interval as the publisher sends new messages. By doing so, you will never get the latest message queued up by the publisher.

What I expect is that the Mosquitto broker tries to send all pending messages one after the other to the client instead of sending one old message when a new one is published.

Maybe someone can help me to understand why this happens or maybe how to overcome this situation?

Comment: What version of mosquitto are you using. Also how are are you processing the messages in the client, are you doing any long running tasks in the message delivery callback?

Answer (score 0):

Queued messages should all be batch delivered when the client reconnects.

They are not queued up and delivered with the same time offset, mosquitto wouldn't even keep time of arrival to be able to do time offset delayed delivery (Time of arrival is kept for MQTT v5 messages because they can now have TTL value, but this is only used to remove expired messages from the queue, not to delay late delivery).

Comment: Hmm, okay. But what you explain would be OK as long as the the queued messages are were send in shorte time intervals than the new messages. Als long as a new message is used as a trigger to send the oldes pending message (and no more than the last) one, you will never ever empty the queue and reach the newest one...

Comment: They should be sent immediately on you reconnecting/subscribing to the topic in question, they are not triggered by anything other than the client reconnecting. If you are queuing/publishing new messages quicker than they can be progressed by the client, the client is the problem, not the broker.

Comment: Yes, overload could cause what you describe. But for testing puposes I send the messages in 5 second intervalls. That should not cause such problems. An the old messages also arrive in 5 second intervalls...

Comment: That is not the case, the messages are delivered immediately, do you have a unique identifier in each message to prove that they are being delayed rather than you just seeing new messages?

Comment: Yes, I do send the current timestamp as a string and I do see timestamps from hours ago, before the subscriber was shut dowsn. And I also unsubsrcibe the topic on shutdown of the subscriber.

Comment: A logged line on the subscriber looks like this:
2020-05-05 08:57:24.313 : [IoT] [3] Topic "public/test3" received with content "DBHOMESRV 2020-05-05T08:52:44+01:00"